# Load balancers for WSO2 products

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, product

Can the Load Balancers like 
Citrix ,
F5 ,
Brocade

work with WSO2 products Like

ESB , 
APIM, 
BPS,
GREG ,
MB

Can you please help with the information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any load balancer that can handle/ load balance Http request should be fine. WSO2 load balancing configurations for WSO2 product clusters can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+a+Cluster#SettingupaCluster-Configuringtheloadbalancer). You can get an idea from that guide and compare any load balancing configuration that you need to do.There it will explain NGINX, Apache Httpd, AWS ELB, and HAProxy configurations.